# Replace alloys with steel rims?

Tags: wheels, citroen, steel

I am in Ireland, so we use summer tyres all year and this is about the only set of rims to be used on the car.

I acquired a 2015 Citroen C3. It has 17 inch alloy rims. I never had alloys before.

Tyres are due for changing soon - and I found that new ones cost a fortune, with anything except admittedly-crappy (C/E rating) budget tyres costing over 100 Euro/piece fitted. Also, I am not a great driver and can sometimes clip a kerb etc - alloys are not easy to repair properly.

I'm thinking of getting a set of steel rims from a breaker. I can store the alloys securely, and when the time comes to sell the car on, I'll have a set of shiny unworn alloys. This was my own idea, but the men at the tyre shop think I should go for it. (I was clear I'm getting the rims from a breaker so this is not about the shop trying to sell me a set of rims).

So, questions:

- Apart from the car looking less cool, what are the downsides of getting steel rims from a breaker and replacing the alloys with them? (I'm not really worried about trims, if the breaker does not have them I can get them from a cheapo shop). Should I expect the car to handle *much* worse? The steering is not very sharp as it is, just because it's a Citroen C3. I sometimes understeer a little, but am getting used to it. This being a 1.2L car, high speed energetic driving is not likely to happen (though it certainly can cruise at 120 kph on a motorway).
- If I do that, should I go for 15 inch or 16 inch? The current tyres are 205/45R17; the tyres to use to keep the diameter more or less the same are 195/60R15 or 195/55R16. The R15 ones are cheaper, but would the handling be significantly better with R16?
- I need to get bolts with them, as the bolts are different for alloys and steels, right? And are bolts specific to the model of the car?

Answer (score 3):

My car came with alloys for summer and steels for winter.

As long as you have the correct size **and** the correct wheelnuts then it will be fine.

One difference is price between 15 and 16, but also “compliance” with rough roads - also depends on the aspect ratio : a 40 is much “harder” than a 60. A 55 or 60 will likely feel softer than the 40 17 you have at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I do feel quite hard on ramps and forest roads, despite the Citroen's famed soft suspension - now I understand why! Now to get the correct wheelnuts - and do I need to replace the bolts too?